# How to open a folder (with GUI) from terminal?

Tags: command-line, directory

I want to place a link/shortcut/launcher in my unity panel (ubuntu 12.10).

I followed [this tutorial](http://handytutorial.com/manually-create-custom-application-launcher-in-ubuntu-12-10-unity/) on handytutorial.com to create a custom launcher and drag it to the panel.

I just need to know which command do I have to input. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to launch?

Comment: I think he is trying to add an URL as  launcher. Midori used to have this, maybe I'll check it out again.

Comment: for ubuntu 20, `xdg-open .` works well.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`gnome-open` does not work for me on 12.04 but `nautilus /path` to open does work.

example: `nautilus /home/john/Downloads`.

Comment: Weird... I'm on 12.04 right now. `gnome-open` works for me. Are you  using Lubuntu? Or Xubuntu?

Comment: Tried it on my box (12.04 LTS running Unity 3D). `gnome-open` doesn't seem to be installed (but you can install it easily). I still prefer doing `nautilus <path>` though, since it requires 0 additional effort.

Comment: Try `xdg-open` instead

Comment: @oaskamay I found out why I have `gnome-open`. I installed gnu-cash, which installed libgnome2-bin (gnome-open is in it) as one of its dependencies.

Comment: The answer from @EricCarvalho works perfectly, thank you very much, and all others as well!

Comment: ubuntu 16, `nautilus dir` still works perfectly

Comment: Works on 18.04, too.

Comment: I like this answer, particularly because after it opens the path in the gui, it ends the process running in the terminal. Running `xdg-open` keeps a running process in the terminal, even after closing the folder gui.

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04, need to use `xdg-open` instead, because I can't find a way to install `gnome-open` any more, and `xdg-open` is installed by default.

Comment: At Ubuntu 22.04 is enough use `open <path/to/directory>` as macOS

Answer (score 117):

If the question is how to open a file/folder, the answer is always *xdg-open*.

From [man xdg-open](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http and https URLs.

In this specific case the commmand

```
xdg-open folder
```

opens *folder* in your default file manager, be it Nautilus, Dolphin, Thunar or anything else.

Comment: Actually I think most applications will behave normally and open a file/url/binary being it the default file type to handle. Eg: blender untitled.blend

Comment: This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio open' instead.

Comment: as of 2020 it is not deprecated

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.10 and can confirm that it still works. I find it more convenient than `nautilus` since it starts the process and let it alone.

Comment: this still works on Fedora 37 2023.

Answer (score 19):

A shortcut to open a folder? If this what you want, the command is:

```
gnome-open </path/to/folder>
```

For example: `gnome-open /home/Tiago/Downloads`.

If it isn't installed run `sudo apt-get install libgnome2-bin`.

Comment: works for me on Ubuntu 15.05

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME Flashback.

Answer (score 16):

Use the command `nautilus <path>`.

So for example: `nautilus /home/oaskamay` will open up my home (`~`) folder.

In addition, if you need to open-up the GUI with root permissions, run `gksu nautilus <path>`. It works with every GUI front-ends too (e.g. `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`).

It's important to note that you should **never** start GUI apps like so `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 10):

`xdg-open` works for me on **ubuntu 16.04**. I only made a copy of this command as `open`:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/xdg-open /usr/bin/open
sudo chmod 775 /usr/bin/open
```

Now you can use it just like on **mac os**:

```
open ./
```

Comment: This might answer the question title, but I fail to see how this lines up with the question.

Comment: Answering the question title seems more important, I found this answer while searching for what was asked in the title. A pity it's just a copy of another answer on the same question, given 3 years earlier...

Comment: At Ubuntu 22.04 is enough use `open <path/to/directory>` as macOS

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple alias named as "open" or "o" etc... in .bashrc

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc

# add personaly open alias
alias open='xdg-open ./'
```

log out account, sign in, open the terminal and write open

Answer (score -1):

Use Midori's app function. When I make an app this way it is added to launchers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a new file with a name of you choice: sudo nano /usr/local/bin/myCommand .
Paste the following command there: nautilus $PWD
Once you have written the code for your command, save and close the file.
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mycommand.
Test your new command:
Add your command to the PATH (If you want to be able to execute your command from any directory, you need to add it to the PATH environment variable):                         
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin to your .bashrc file.

Restart your terminal or run source ~/.bashrc