# How do I change or delete the album cover image shown in rhythmbox?

Tags: command-line, rhythmbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and I have some wrong covers associated with albums.

I've already disabled the cover plug-in, but the wrong covers that were downloaded are still being shown when I play the songs they are associated with.

I want to know how to delete these covers so that Rhythmbox won't show them anymore.

Maybe if someone could give the terminal code to access the Rhythmbox cover folder so I can delete these cover images, or something like that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All rhythmbox covers are held in a database format called *[trivial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Database)*.

This database is found in the folder `~/.cache/rhythmbox/album-art`.

In theory you can write some code or use tools such as `[tdbdump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/tdbdump.8.html)` to interrogate the database, but in practise it is easier just to delete the folder and its contents.

Don't worry - it recreates itself when rhythmbox starts and you next add album-art.

If you are using Rhythmbox v2.97 and later you can instead drag-and-drop pictures from Nautilus onto the album-art plugin and it will update your album-art - make sure you are playing your music track first when doing this.

[image: pic]

If you are using Rhythmbox v2.96 you cannot use this drag-and-drop technique.  However, if you use my rhythmbox plugin [coverart-browser](https://askubuntu.com/a/145282/14356), you can similarly drag-and-drop pictures onto your albums.

[image: pic2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I couldn't find that cache folder. Can you tell me how to acess it?

Comment: I was able to find a way to open it with gnome-open command with this link: http://askubuntu.com/a/265642/162053. Thank you very much for the answer. Now I can delete those misrelated folders...

Answer (score 0):

Force stop your Music playing app. Connect your device to a PC. Use the search function to search your phone (phone storage or SD card where you store your music) for albumart.jpg. In Ubuntu the results appear as icons, in Windows right click - search . You can delete the offending icons, then use whatever app you use to try find new album art. You can be more specific by searching: \albumthumbs , \android\data\com.android.providers.media\albumthumbs or each individual album folder.