# How to add or replace album art in rhythmbox?

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox

Is there a way to add custom album art to a song or replace album album art of a song in rhythmbox.

Comment: What version of RhythmBox? stock std. or latest ?

Comment: Isn't this question the same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/334298/how-do-i-change-or-delete-the-album-cover-image-shown-in-rhythmbox/334413#334413