# Open a folder in a Graphic File Manager from a terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, directory

How can I open a folder in a GFM (in a files window) from the terminal?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: `[gksu] nautilus /path/to/directory`

Comment: try [How to open a folder (with GUI) from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265641/how-to-open-a-folder-with-gui-from-terminal)

Comment: I thought you meant that you want to open a folder in an image program like XNviewmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly e.g.

```
nautilus ~
```

were ~ is your home folder and can be replaced by the folder you have in mind.